# how to construct image from hex values/strings

Tags: android, image

I have a text file in sd card named file.txt which contains a hex values of a JPG image.
These  values is received from a hardware camera. Now i have to read this text file from sd card and then need to construct a JPG image from these  hex values.
 I tried over 1 week but couldn't able to construct the JPG image.
Can anyone help me???

N:B: My camera is "LinkSprite JPEG Color Camera"

Comment: Without knowing the camera manufacturer and camera model it might be hard to guess how image is encoded...

Comment: My camera is LinkSprite JPEG Color Camera

Comment: I just googled for it and found [this](http://robotic-controls.com/learn/arduino/linksprite-jpeg-camera) solution in Python...